# put text inline aside a checkbox

Tags: lightning-web-components, css

I am desperately trying to put a h1 element right by the side of a checkbox, and I can't seem to do it.

```
<div>
    <lightning-input onchange={select} type="checkbox" name={index}></lightning-input>
    <h1>Promo: <span style="font-weight: bold;">{promotion.name}</span></h1>
</div>
```

I tried changing the display of the checkbox to block, then I tried that with both the h1 and input elements, and then tried with a inline-block display and it didn't do anything. The input takes the whole line and the h1 appears below. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Would `<div style="display:flex;">` do the trick on your div?. Also keep in mind that the label is required, and if you don't want it you may use `variant="label-hidden"` together with the label

Comment: I'll try that! And i'll add the label, thanks

Answer (score -1):

So, Sergio Alcocer's answer works. adding a display:flex to the div containing the input and the h1 did the trick. Thanks Sergio!